# How can I attach key event from Android soft keyboard without EditText?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to attach key event from soft keyboard without EditText.
I already override some method. But not work.

Here is my code that open soft keyboard.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  public void OpenKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
      Log.d("displatch", "clicked.."); // NOT-WORKING..

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
      Log.d("onKeyDown", "clicked.."); // NOT-WORKING..

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

Please find a solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement KeyEvent.Callback

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KeyEvent.Callback
{
//...
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            moveShip(MOVE_LEFT);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F:
            moveShip(MOVE_RIGHT);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_J:
            fireMachineGun();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K:
            fireMissile();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
}
```

you cuold read more in [Handling Keyboard Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html)

Comment: Is there any methods to track event of softkeyboards?

Answer (score -1):

You must bind the onKeyListener to your editText.

```
edttext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    //do something here
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

or try this.

```
edittext.setonKeyListener(this);
```

Comment: I DON'T WANT TO USE EDIT TEXT